# What's an alternative term for "age groups"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to employ the formation "age groups" in a sentence worded in a different way. Is "age fragments" right to employ? If not, what else could be used?

Comment: Why do you find "age groups" unsuitable?

Comment: is the answer to your comment relates to my question in any way ?

Comment: You're asking for an alternative to "age groups", knowing why this term is unsuitable for your use may influence the choice of alternative terms.

Comment: _Age fragments_ makes no sense. I don't know the context, but would 'people of similar age' work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How large are the groups in question?  For example, we use "generation" to group together people who were born over the course of approximately two decades, but we would not use that for people born in a single year.

Comment: The response would be different if you were creating a SurveyMonkey question as opposed to discussing an academic paper on demographics or medicine.

Comment: . . age range .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A perfect synonym is "*age bracket*".

> ([macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/age-bracket)) **age bracket** the range between two particular ages
> people in the 50–60 age bracket

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/age-group?q=age+group)) **age group** noun,
> Eng /ˈeɪdʒ ɡruːp/
> Am /ˈeɪdʒ ɡruːp/
> (also less frequent age bracket) people of a similar age or within a particular range of ages

Comment: thanks ! that's all i needed, could we employ it in the plural as age brackets ?

Comment: I see *age bracket* more often for informal contexts, such as surveys.

Comment: @PatrickSchulz Yes, the plural is no problem: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=age+brackets&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cage%20brackets%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 21):

**cohort** (n.)

> A group of individuals having a statistical factor (such as age or
> class membership) in common in a demographic study
>
> *a cohort of
> premedical students*
> *the cohort of people born in the 1980s* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohort)

> A group of people with a common statistical characteristic.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cohort)

---

> The low growth rate for the under-20 **cohort** reflects the drop in
> the fertility rate from a peak of 3.61 in 1960 to a low of 1.76 in
> 1978, a fall-off that gave rise to the baby-buster **cohort**. [P. E. Peterson; *The Social Security Primer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Social_Security_Primer/uXuTDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20low%20growth%20rate%20for%20the%20under-20%20cohort%20reflects%20the%20drop%20in%20the&pg=PT39&printsec=frontcover)

> The youngest two **cohorts** were aged 9–10 years (**cohort** one) and
> 11–12 years (**cohort** two) and were still in primary school... The
> next two **cohorts** were aged 13–14 years (**cohort** three) and
> 15–16 years (**cohort** four)... [L. B. Hendry et al.; *Young
> People's Leisure and Lifestyles*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Young_People_s_Leisure_and_Lifestyles/1--IAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=10-20%20years%20cohort&pg=PA23&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I've seen *cohort* in more academic papers regarding demographics.

Comment: @rajah9 Yes, the OP mentions a sentence, but doesn't give it to us and doesn't tell us what it's part of.

Comment: @rajah9 My impression is that this use of _cohort_ started off in academic/scientific use, but has been gaining a little currency in general usage.  It's still probably less likely to be understood than a general term such as ‘age group’, though.

Comment: Granted, the OP provided little detail but I'm not sure this is a good fit. "Choose your cohort :" and then a list of ages wouldn't make sense to me

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Where does it say "Choose your cohort"? In any case, if the same question is asked, it could be closed and linked to this question. I think *cohort* is useful info.

Comment: @gidds I agree that *cohort* is less recognizable than *age group* to the general population. I did a quick search on scholar.google.com for *covid cohort study* and got 1.9M hits. A search for *covid "age group" study* got 0.2M hits. My conclusion is that *cohort* is much more recognizable to the academic community.

Comment: @DjinTonic It doesn't.